# how to read the body of a response

Tags: node.js, react-native, http, google-cloud-functions, expo

I'm using react Native Expo and firebase for my project.

I have a button in my application that trigger a Google cloud Function but I always have an undefined body in the response.

This is the call of the cloud function

```
const getResponse = async () => {
    await fetch("https://*****************************************/test", {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({
            user_id: userID,
            rep_id: request
        })
    }).then(response => {
        //console.log("body is " + response.body.needToBeVoted);
        console.log("body is " + JSON.stringify(response.body));
        console.log("status is " + JSON.stringify(response.status));
        console.log("all response is " + JSON.stringify(response));
        console.log("bodyUsed " + JSON.stringify(response.bodyUsed));
        if (response.bodyUsed && response.body != null) {
            if (isNaN(response.body)) {
                setSteps("result");
            } else {
                setSteps("bills");
            }
        }
        setResponse(response);
    })
}
```

and this is my log

```
body is undefined
status is 200
all response is {"type":"default","status":200,"ok":true,"statusText":"","headers":{"map":{"x-cloud-trace-context":"9ea739ca548e85dbaf9f385244bf9def;o=1","content-type":"application/json; charset=utf-8","etag":"W/\"2-l9Fw4VUO7kr8CvBlt4zaMCqXZ0w\"","server":"Google Frontend","function-execution-id":"l16yrcw4wa9g","x-powered-by":"Express","alt-svc":"h3=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-29=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-T051=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=\":443\"; ma=2592000,quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"46,43\"","date":"Tue, 03 Aug 2021 11:16:20 GMT","content-length":"2"}},"url":"https://***************************/test","bodyUsed":false,"_bodyInit":{"_data":{"size":2,"offset":0,"blobId":"7B0C2BD0-ADEC-4F4D-A3C0-35FDF80C2987","type":"application/json","name":"test","__collector":{}}},"_bodyBlob":{"_data":{"size":2,"offset":0,"blobId":"7B0C2BD0-ADEC-4F4D-A3C0-35FDF80C2987","type":"application/json","name":"test","__collector":{}}}}
bodyUsed false
```

I know my cloud function works well when I check their log but I'm not sure what i have to use to answer

```
res.send(needToBeVoted);
res.json({ data: needToBeVoted });
```

I tried the both but it's the same result.

If someone have any idea of what I have to do to read the body of my response let help me !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to use `.json()` and your function is async so you can use `await` instead of Promise chaining:

```js
const getResponse = async () => {
  try {
    const reqResponse = await fetch("https://*****************************************/test", {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({
        user_id: userID,
        rep_id: request
      })
    })
    const response = await reqResponse.json()
    //console.log("body is " + response.body.needToBeVoted);
    console.log("body is " + JSON.stringify(response.body));
    console.log("status is " + response.status);
    console.log("all response is " + JSON.stringify(response));
    console.log("bodyUsed " + JSON.stringify(response.bodyUsed));
    if (response.bodyUsed && response.body != null) {
      if (isNaN(response.body)) {
        setSteps("result");
      } else {
        setSteps("bills");
      }
    }
    setResponse(response);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but when I try it display nothing ```body is undefined
status is undefined
all response is []
bodyUsed undefined```

Comment: @xXx_Ninj4_Kill3r_xXx can you `console.log(reqResponse)` and share the whole output? Mayeb using a [Gist](https://gist.github.com)

Comment: I just got that ```reqResponse = [object Object]```

Comment: @xXx_Ninj4_Kill3r_xXx `console.log(JSON.stringify(reqResponse))` and `console.log(JSON.stringify(response))` please so the content is vvisible.

Comment: Can you confirm the API is actually returning a JSON ?

Comment: When I stringify it i have that = ```reqResponse = {"type":"default","status":200,"ok":true,"statusText":"","headers":{"map":{"x-cloud-trace-context":"3fdd95b9edd548634b1d2c63c2bb8ebb;o=1","content-type":"application/json; charset=utf-8","etag":"W/\"2-l9Fw4VUO7kr8CvBlt4zaMCqXZ0w\"","server":"Google Frontend","function-execution-id":"03k5b1c9ojt2","x-powered-by":"Express","alt-svc":"h3=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-29=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-T05..."; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=\":443\";"``` the message is too long, yes it is and it's globaly the same message i put in my question

Comment: OK I change something in my cloud function and it work well now, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing a .then call.

```
  .then(res =>  res.json())
    .then(response => { all of your logs above })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Also add the catch for a better error handling

Comment: Thanks for your answer but when I try it display nothing ```body is undefined status is undefined all response is [] bodyUsed undefined```